# Copy data backups (AZ File storage) to GCP Storage

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-files

What is the best solution to transfer a huge amount of data  (~few TB) from Azure File Storage to GCP Storage?. It's not an Azure Blob Storage, so I can`t use AzCopy and Data transfer option on the GCP side. Is there any other 'easy' way to transfer that kind of data?

Comment: Are you referring to [Azure Files](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/#overview) and transfer to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage)?

Comment: @JMGelilio Yes, exactly. I want to transfer files from Azure File Storage to GCP Storage.

Comment: 1) Review data transfer pricing for both Azure and Google Cloud. 2) The simplest method is to mount the Azure File Share on a system in Azure and then use **gsutil rsync** to copy from the share to Google Cloud Storage. 3) However, even though a few TB is not huge today, it will still take days (a week) to copy the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, unfortunately there is no service in Azure that allows to copy data from File Storage to GCP Storage. Even in Azure Data Factory, which is highly used to copy data, GCP Storage can only be used as source but not as a sink, i.e., you can only copy data from GCP Storage to Azure storage. Please refer document for more details on [ADF supported data stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores).

So, the alternative is you can copy the data to Blob Storage and then copy to GCP Storage using Google cloud data transfer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's an docker image of an agent: https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/securitasmachina2022/securitasmachinaoffsiteagent

Do note there's a 5TiB file size limit on google storage buckets